# attr com carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

Olá, estou tentando utilizar o carousel dinamicamente, alterando quando for a url for selecionada. Mas após clicar o iframe principal muda e mostra a seguinte mensagem: "Talvez tenha sido movido ou excluído"

A Ponte

```
<body>

    <header>

    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="videos" class="container" style="margin-top:10px">
                <h2>Principais vídeos</h2>
                <hr>

                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/257707149"></iframe>

                <div class="row thumbnails owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="items" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220823786">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <img src="imagem/lucas.jpg" alt="Video">
                        <h3>Clipe musical</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="items" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/254645625">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <img src="imagem/fashion.jpg" alt="Video">
                        <h3>Fashion Video</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="items" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/257707149">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <img src="imagem/cah.jpg" alt="Video">
                        <h3>Fashion Video</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="items" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/256980858">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <img src="imagem/salvando.jpg" alt="Video">
                        <h3>Clipe musical</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <footer>
        </footer>

    <script src="jquery\jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="OwlCarousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js\efeitos.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(".thumbnails .items").on("click", function(){

                $("iframe").attr("src",+$(this).attr("href"));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: É só tirar aquele '+' do +$(this).attr("href")

Comment: muito obrigada!!!!